# Example of the continuity of the Fredholm index

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Consider the space of square-summable sequences $\ell^2 =\{(a_0,a_1,\ldots) : \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|^2<\infty\}$. Let $I$ denote the identity on $\ell^2$ and define the unilateral shift operator
\begin{align}
S(a_0,a_1,\ldots) = (a_1,a_2,\ldots).
\end{align}

It's well-known that $I$ and $S$ are both Fredholm (they have finite dimensional kernels and cokernels) with Fredholm indices $\text{ind}(I) = 0$ and $\text{ind}(S) = 1$. Moreover, it is known that the Fredholm index is a continuous function from $\mathfrak{F}(\ell_2) = \{\text{Fredholm operators on }\ell^2\}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. Each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ corresponds to a particular connected component of $\mathfrak{F}(\ell_2)$. In particular, $I$ and $S$ belong to distinct connected components.

Now, consider the path $X_s = s\,\text{id} + (1-s)S$, $s\in[0,1]$. Since the Fredholm index is continuous, $X_s$ must leave the set of Fredholm operators somewhere along the path. From what I can tell, $X_s$ is Fredholm for all $s\neq 1/2$. The index is $1$ for $s<1/2$ and $0$ for $s>1/2$.

**My question is**: which of the kernel or cokernel of $X_{1/2}$ is infinite dimensional? If neither are, then what invalidates the "Fredholmness" of $X_{1/2}$?

Here's my attempt at answering:
\begin{align}
X_{1/2}(a_0,a_1,\ldots) = \frac{1}{2}(a_0+a_1,a_1+a_2,\ldots).
\end{align}
So,
\begin{align}
\ker X_{1/2} = \{(a_0,a_1,\ldots)\in\ell^2 : a_n+a_{n+1} = 0,\,\,\forall n\}
\end{align}
Consider a sequence $(a_0,a_1,\ldots) \in \ker X_{1/2}$. If $a_0=0$, then $a_n=0$ for all $n$. If $a_0\neq 0$, we can take $a_0=1$ without loss of generality. Then $a_n = (-1)^n$, and so the sequence is not square-summable. We conclude that $\ker X_{1/2} = \{0\}$, which is trivially finite-dimensional.

So, the cokernel must be infinite-dimensional, right? Well, in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ (such as $\ell^2$), $\text{coker}\,T \cong \ker T^*$ with $T^*$ the adjoint of an operator $T:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$. We have
\begin{align}
X_{1/2}^*(a_0,a_1,\ldots) = \frac{1}{2}(a_0,a_1+a_0,\ldots)
\end{align}
An element of $\ker X_{1/2}^*$ necessarily has $a_0=0$ which, in turn, yields $a_n=0$ for all $n$. So $\ker X_{1/2}^* = \{0\}$, from which we conclude the finite-dimensionality of $\text{coker}\,X_{1/2}$. Hence, I am tempted to say $X_{1/2}$ is Fredholm with index $0-0 = 0$. What am I doing wrong here? Am I incorrectly using $\text{coker}\,X_{1/2} \cong \ker X_{1/2}^*$, or is it something else? Is $X_s$ only Fredholm for $s=0$ and $s=1$? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: @Ruy and @RyszardSzwarc helped me arrive at the answer in the comments below. I'd also like to call attention to this similar question: [Error in the calulation of the spectrum of the image of right shift operator in the Calkin algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075873/error-in-the-calulation-of-the-spectrum-of-the-image-of-right-shift-operator-in)

Comment: The cokernel equation you are using only holds for operators with closed range.  Have you checked this for $X_{1/2}$?

Comment: As for your last question, the answer is no because the set of Fredholm operators is open.

Comment: $I\pm S$ is not a Fredholm operator as its range is dense but not equal the whole space. Thus it is not closed.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc's remark follows from the well known fact that the essential spectrum of $S$ is the unit circle.  From this it also follows that, for real $t$, one has that  $t-S$ is Fredholm iff $t\neq \pm 1$.

Comment: @Ruy This well known fact can be shown by hand for the shift operatorr. It seems that the asker was not familiar with that.

Comment: Thank you @Ruy and RyszardSzwarc. First, thanks for recasting my question in terms of the essential spectrum of $S$. Indeed, I am essentially asking for it. Second, let me see if I understand. If my computation is correct, $(I+S)(a_0,a_1,...) = (b_0,b_1,...)$ if and only if $a_m = \sum_{n=m}^\infty (-1)^{n+m}b_n$. So, I am assuming that there is a  set of square-summable sequences $(b_0,b_1,...)$ such that the corresponding $(a_0,a_1,...)$ is not in $\ell^2$. Do you have an example? If I were to guess, I would say $\sum_{n}|b_n|^2$ is convergent, but not absolutely convergent,

Comment: If $(b_n)_n$ is not in $\ell^1$ then the $a_n$ are not even well defined.

Comment: I wouldn't focus so much on vectors!  The standard proof that the essential spectrum of the shift coincides with the circle goes like this: noting that the essential spectrum is the spectrum in the Calking algebra $B(H)/K(H)$, first try to prove that the shift is unitary there. This will immediately imply that the spectrum is contained in the circle.

Comment: Thanks @Ruy! I had run into the Calkin algebra in a few references and assumed it might be overkill - I was wrong. It is much more elegant than dealing with the the kernel and ranges explicitly. I see that $[S]\in B(\ell^2)/K(\ell^2)$ is unitary ($S^*S$ and $SS^*$ are equal to the identity modulo a compact operator). Hence its spectrum is on the unit circle (actually equal to it). Thus [S] is not invertible there, and so $\lambda - S$ is not Fredholm for $|\lambda|=1$. In particular $I+S$ seems to have an infinite-dimensional cokernel (since the kernel is provably finite). Great, thanks again!